# Sublime Text: Keyboard shortcut for opening user settings on Windows

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

Is the shortcut for opening the user settings in Sublime Text in Windows / Linux `Ctrl + ,`? I'm assuming this because the command for opening user settings on Mac is `Cmd + ,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

As of [build 3124](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), the name of the option is now `Preferences: Settings`. Because of Sublime's fuzzy matching, you can just type in something like `prefs` to narrow down the options.

### Original Answer

If you are referring to the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file, then you can do it in a couple steps:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette.
2. Start typing in `settings - user`. Eventually you'll see the option.
3. Select it.

Answer (score 14):

The <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> keyboard shortcut is OSX specific - the default keybindings for Linux and Windows do not contain anything to open the user settings file.

However, you can add it yourself in the user keybindings file.

In Build 3114, this is accessible from the Preferences -> Keybindings - User menu:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+,"], "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "${packages}/User/Preferences.sublime-settings"} }
```

In Build 3118, this is accessible from the Preferences -> Keybindings menu:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+,"], "command": "edit_settings", "args":
    {
        "base_file": "${packages}/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
        "default": "// Settings in here override those in \"Default/Preferences.sublime-settings\",\n// and are overridden in turn by syntax-specific settings.\n{\n\t$0\n}\n"
    }
},
```

Comment: Great! Just what I needed. Works better than the accepted answer.